# Maui: Why the content inside the Shell.TitleView disappears every second time?

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell

I have a MAUI app with a Flyout menu.

In the navigation bar beside the burger I show the title and a button (navigating to the user's profile settings).
When I open the app on Android device or Android emulator **every second page** I enter from the menu, the content inside the `Shell.TitleView` disappears.

The order of the selected pages does not matter. That means for example, if I open `FirstPage`, `ThirdPage`, `SecondPage`, `FirstPage` in this order, then `ThirdPage` and the second opening of `FirstPage` has no content in `Shell.TitleView`.

The same happens, when I use a `HorizontalStackLayout`.
But when I use just a `Label` directly in `Shell.TitleView` (without a container like a `Grid`) then it works fine and on any page the `Label` is visible. It also works fine on Windows Machine.

It is also interesting that when I open a second page, the content of the `Grid` is displayed correctly for a short moment (matching title of the page), but disappears after about 0.7 seconds.

What is the problem and how it can be solved?
Does anyone know of a workaround?

You can find the full example project here:
https://mehlhop.com/forum/ProfileApp.7z (113 KB)

A video (kind of screencast) you find here (without download): https://mehlhop.com/forum/20230522_181856_1.mp4

AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ProfileApp.Views"
    x:Class="ProfileApp.AppShell"
    FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">

    <Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" BackgroundColor="Red">
            <Label Grid.Column="0" x:Name="title" Style="{StaticResource labelPageTitle}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="NN" Style="{StaticResource ButtonToProfilePage}" Clicked="ProfileButton_OnClickedAsync"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>

    <FlyoutItem Title="First" >
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FirstPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Second">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SecondPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Third">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ThirdPage}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

AppShell.xaml.cs:

```cs
using ProfileApp.Views;

namespace ProfileApp;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ProfilePage), typeof(ProfilePage));
    }

    protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigated(args);
        title.Text = Shell.Current.CurrentItem.Title;
    }

    private async void ProfileButton_OnClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Shell.Current.CurrentPage is ProfilePage) return;

        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(ProfilePage), true);
        title.Text = "Profile Settings";
    }
}
```

MauiProgram.cs (detail):

```cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        });

    var services = builder.Services;
    services.AddTransient<AppShell>();
    services.AddTransient<FirstPage>();
    services.AddTransient<SecondPage>();
    services.AddTransient<ThirdPage>();
    services.AddTransient<ProfilePage>();
}
```

Comment: The issue is that Shell Title View disappears after navigating through tabs (ios & Android) and this is a known issue that being tracked in the links afterwards, you can follow up there.

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13347

Comment: Also the related https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10587

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a workaround.
The problem with the disappearing of the `TitleView` does not happen, when you reorganise the menu navigation.

Part of AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<Shell.FlyoutHeader>
    <views:FlyoutHeader />
</Shell.FlyoutHeader>

// defines the start page
<ShellContent FlyoutItemIsVisible="False" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:FirstPage}" Route="FirstPage"/>

<MenuItem ClassId="FirstPage" Text="First" Clicked="MenuItem_OnClicked" />

<MenuItem ClassId="SecondPage" Text="Second" Clicked="MenuItem_OnClicked" />
```

Part of AppShell.xaml.cs:

```cs
public AppShell(/*...*/)
{
    //...
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(FirstPage), typeof(FirstPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SecondPage), typeof(SecondPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ThirdPage), typeof(ThirdPage));
}

private async void MenuItem_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    var classId = menuItem?.ClassId;
    switch (classId)
    {
        case null:
            return;
        case "FirstPage":
            await Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
            break;
        case "SecondPage":
            await Current.GoToAsync(nameof(SecondPage), true);
            break;
        case "ThirdPage":
            //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but can you expand a bit on your answer? As of the time of writing this comment, the issue still hasn't been fixed yet by the MAUI team, so we are stuck with workarounds. Can you explain exacltly which part of your answer is fixing the problem and how it's fixing it?

Comment: @Play4u Replacing the bugy standard fixed it, I would say.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not following but which buggy standard are you specifically referring to here? I'm facing the exact same issue as OP and I cannot ship the app with such a fundamental bug